# What permissions are need to get all process connections on a unix based OS remotely using netstat

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, user-permissions, netstat

I have permissions to ssh to a particular unix based machine (with /proc filesystem). However when I try to ssh and run netstat -taupen remotely. I don't see the PIDs of the processes. E.g -

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
  tcp        0      0 10.10.27.42:80          :::*                    LISTEN      1000       16082      -                   
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7474          :::*                    LISTEN      110        16568      -
```

The PID is shown as - above. 
My question is what permissions do I need to see the PIDs for a process using the netstat command

Answer (score 1):

You can only view the PIDs (and hence process names) of the processes that have EUID (Effective User ID) same as the invoking user of `netstat` i.e. the invoking user is the owner.

To get the PIDs/Process names of all processes that have sockets enlisted, you need to run the `netstat` command as superuser (UID 0), or impersonate the superuser using `sudo` (**preferred**) or look for any kernel capability unit (if there is) that provides that.